# Parsing json using jq

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I am trying to get the difficulty value out of a JSON structure using jq on the linux command line:

```
./jq '{result: .difficulty}' status.txt
```

(The JSON is held in a file called status.txt - shown below) But try as I might I keep getting:

```
{
  "result": null
}
```

Returned, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
{
   "result":{
      "version":1030000,
      "protocolversion":60001,
      "walletversion":60000,
      "balance":2600.00020000,
      "blocks":16042,
      "connections":6,
      "proxy":"",
      "difficulty":28.20775972,
      "testnet":false,
      "keypoololdest":1382340615,
      "keypoolsize":94,
      "paytxfee":0.00000000,
      "mininput":0.00010000,
      "unlocked_until":0,
      "errors":""
   },
   "error":null,
   "id":"curltest"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to access to `result` object and inside it extract the `difficulty` value:

```
./jq '.result.difficulty' status.txt
```

It yields:

```
28.20775972
```

Comment: what should i do to retrieve the `curltest` value of `ID`. I am facing  issue when using the for loop